# How to make dynamic fields in a form validated and required?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to add dynamic fields to a form, these fields will have 2 as minimum and then you can add more, each one added should be validated and required if it's been left there when saving, these fields can be removed. My question is how to make them required when not all items will have these fields.

What i'm creating is a question that when it's response type is set as multiple choice then these fields will appear with two options being mandatory and the possibility to add more. So these fields are not always required only if the response type is multiple choice.

I'm not sure where to add that the fields are required, I've tried to add it in the vue rules but that doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't get validated, the question will save without the mandatory two options.

This is the code I have so far in my form, where the options are added

```
<div v-if="form.response_type_id === 2">
    <el-divider></el-divider>
    <el-row>
        <el-col :span="22">
            <p class="el-form-item__label">Opciones</p>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="2">
            <div class="btn-link-plus action-button" @click="addOption()">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </div>
        </el-col>
    </el-row>
    <div v-for="(option, index) in questionOptions" :key="index">
        <el-row>
            <el-col :span="22">
                <el-form-item prop="option">
                    <el-input v-model="option.option"></el-input>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
            <el-col :span="2">
                <div class="btn-link-delete action-button" @click="removeOption(index)"
                    :disabled="trashDisabled">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </div>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my SaveRequest for the questions

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'question' => 'required',
        'survey_section_id' => 'required|exists:survey_section,id',
        'response_type_id' => 'required|exists:response_types,id',
        'optional' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

I would like that if a person is creating a question and chooses multiple choice they are required to add two options always, and that they are unable to save until that is true.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what is the name of the input that will hold these multiple options?

Comment: @lagbox Its called `questionOptions`

Answer (score 0):

you can use requireIf

```
public function rules()
{
return [
    'question' => 'required',
    'survey_section_id' => 'required|exists:survey_section,id',
    'response_type_id' => 'required|exists:response_types,id',
    'optional' => Rule::requiredIf($request->response_type_id()=='multiple')
];
}
```

remember to import use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Comment: in my rules there is no `$request`, should i just do `response_type_id == 2`

Comment: why there is not $request?

Comment: I'm inside a Request.php file in this case SaveQuestionRequest.php, the code on the bottom is all that's in that file.

Comment: @AlexGuerrero the Form Request is a Request so it has all the request inputs, `$this->response_type_id` or `$this->input('response_type_id')`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
return [
    ...
    'questionOptions' => 'required_if:response_type_id,2|array|min:2',
];
```

`questionOptions` is only required when `response_type_id` is 2; `questionOptions` must then be an array with a minimum of 2 items.

If you want the array to be exactly 2 items you can switch `min:2` out for `size:2`.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Rules - Available Rules - required_if](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-required-if)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Rules - Available Rules - array](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-array)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Rules - Available Rules - min](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-min)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Rules - Available Rules - size](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-size)

Comment: I tried this, and it still saves without checking for this, am I supposed to call this somewhere else?

Comment: its just the `rules` method for the form request, just make sure the form request is type hinted on the controller method you want to use it for

Comment: I have it like this, `public function store(SaveQuestionRequest $request)` and `public function update(SaveQuestionRequest $request)`